# What's SE's markdown format on pandoc?

Tags: support, markdown

I've [tried](http://pandoc.org/try/) converting with pretty much all of them, mostly from a mediawiki excerpt, and none produced a perfect result. I've found strict markdown to be the closest, but it's still off; the links come out empty, and — would it be too much to ask? — the footnotes are not included and formatted.

For instance, this excerpt from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy):

[image]

… comes out as:

```
**Democracy** ( **, literally "rule by people"), in modern usage, has
three senses all for a system of government where the citizens exercise
power by [voting]. In a [direct democracy], the citizens as a whole form
a governing body, and vote directly on each issue, e.g. on the passage
of a particular tax law. In a [representative democracy] the citizens
elect representatives from among themselves. These representative meet
to form a governing body, such as a [legislature]. In a [constitutional
democracy] the powers of the majority are exercised within the framework
of a representative democracy, but the constitution limits the majority
and protects the minority, usually through the enjoyment by all of
certain individual rights, e.g. freedom of speech, or freedom of
association.[1][2] Democracy is sometimes referred to as "rule of the
majority".[3] Democracy is a system of processing conflicts in which
outcomes depend on what participants do, but no single force controls
what occurs and its outcomes.

[1] [Oxford English Dictionary][]: *Democracy*.

[2] 

[3] 

  [voting]: Vote "wikilink"
  [direct democracy]: direct_democracy "wikilink"
  [representative democracy]: representative_democracy "wikilink"
  [legislature]: legislature "wikilink"
  [constitutional democracy]: constitutional_democracy "wikilink"
  [Oxford English Dictionary]: Oxford_English_Dictionary "wikilink"
```

… rendering as:

> **Democracy** ( **, literally "rule by people"), in modern usage, has
>   three senses all for a system of government where the citizens exercise
>   power by voting. In a direct democracy, the citizens as a whole form
>   a governing body, and vote directly on each issue, e.g. on the passage
>   of a particular tax law. In a representative democracy the citizens
>   elect representatives from among themselves. These representative meet
>   to form a governing body, such as a legislature. In a constitutional
>   democracy the powers of the majority are exercised within the framework
>   of a representative democracy, but the constitution limits the majority
>   and protects the minority, usually through the enjoyment by all of
>   certain individual rights, e.g. freedom of speech, or freedom of
>   association.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uBrS.png)[2] Democracy is sometimes referred to as "rule of the
>   majority".[3] Democracy is a system of processing conflicts in which
>   outcomes depend on what participants do, but no single force controls
>   what occurs and its outcomes.
>
> 1[]: *Democracy*.
>
> [2]
>
> [3]

Ideally, I'd like it to yield that:

> **Democracy** ([Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_language): δημοκρατία *dēmokraa thetía*, literally "rule by people"), in modern usage, has three senses all for a system of government where the citizens exercise power by [voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vote). In a [direct democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_democracy), the citizens as a whole form a governing body, and vote directly on each issue, e.g. on the passage of a particular tax law. In a [representative democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representative_democracy) the citizens elect representatives from among themselves. These representative meet to form a governing body, such as a [legislature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legislature). In a [constitutional democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutional_democracy) the powers of the majority are exercised within the framework of a representative democracy, but the constitution limits the majority and protects the minority, usually through the enjoyment by all of
>   certain individual rights, e.g. freedom of speech, or freedom of association.<sup>1 2</sup> Democracy is sometimes referred to as "rule of the majority".<sup>3</sup> Democracy is a system of processing conflicts in which
>   outcomes depend on what participants do, but no single force controls
>   what occurs and its outcomes.
>
> <sub>1. [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary): *Democracy*.</sub>
>
> <sub>2. Watkins, Frederick (1970). *Encyclopædia Britannica* (Hardcover). **7** (Expo '70 ed.). William Benton. pp. 215–223. ISBN [0-85229-135-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-85229-135-3).</sub>
>
> <sub>3. ["Democracy – Definition of Democracy by Merriam-Webster"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/democracy).</sub>

And I haven't even broached the topic of math notation yet!

Answer (score 4):

The links come out empty because pandoc is a syntax converter, and does not have Wikipedia's templates built in—those templates are not part of MediaWiki syntax.

Consider that the excerpt text starts with two templates: `'''Democracy''' ({{lang-gr|δημοκρατία}} ''{{lang|grc|dēmokraa thetía}}'', literally "rule by people")`

If we ignore the templates (because they're undefined anyway) that text effectively just looks like this:

```
'''Democracy''' ( '''', literally "rule by people")
```

and that gets converted to the following:

```
**Democracy** ( **, literally "rule by people")
```

... which is correct.

This also means it doesn't understand the citation templates further down in the excerpt. If we remove the templates, we instead get [this conversion](http://pandoc.org/try/?text=%27%27%27Democracy%27%27%27+(%2C+literally+%22rule+by+people%22)%2C+in+modern+usage%2C+has+three+senses+all+for+a+system+of+government+where+the+citizens+exercise+power+by+%5B%5BVote%7Cvoting%5D%5D.+In+a+%5B%5Bdirect+democracy%5D%5D%2C+the+citizens+as+a+whole+form+a+governing+body%2C+and+vote+directly+on+each+issue%2C+e.g.+on+the+passage+of+a+particular+tax+law.+In+a+%5B%5Brepresentative+democracy%5D%5D+the+citizens+elect+representatives+from+among+themselves.+These+representative+meet+to+form+a+governing+body%2C+such+as+a+%5B%5Blegislature%5D%5D.+In+a+%5B%5Bconstitutional+democracy%5D%5D+the+powers+of+the+majority+are+exercised+within+the+framework+of+a+representative+democracy%2C+but+the+constitution+limits+the+majority+and+protects+the+minority%2C+usually+through+the+enjoyment+by+all+of+certain+individual+rights%2C+e.g.+freedom+of+speech%2C+or+freedom+of+association.+Democracy+is+sometimes+referred+to+as+%22rule+of+the+majority%22.+Democracy+is+a+system+of+processing+conflicts+in+which+outcomes+depend+on+what+participants+do%2C+but+no+single+force+controls+what+occurs+and+its+outcomes.+&from=mediawiki&to=markdown_strict) which generates markdown accurate enough to the best of its knowledge—which is correct, including that it interprets `[[Vote|voting]]` as a link to the url "Vote".

So if you want to convert MediaWiki text to Markdown, you'll need to put in a bit of work patching up the parts the pandoc converter doesn't know how to manage.

Comment: Thanks, @doppelgreener. Looks like that "bit of work" is mechanical enough to be automated into a [filter](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Pandoc-Filters), no?

Comment: @AndréLevy Handling lang and cite templates looks like a job for filters going by the filter documentation, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're out of luck, since Stack Exchange use a custom markdown, forked from the strict if I'm not mistaken.

However, you can see the full source code [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown), as far as I can tell it's still what being used all around SE.

So with that source code you can probably build whatever it is you try to build.

Comment: Uphill battle for me, @ShadowWizard… Was hoping a… wizard might know their way around markdown and python to whip up a [filter](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Pandoc-Filters) faster than I ever could 